# JsonConvert Returning Arrary of Empty Objects [{} {} {} {}]

Tags: c#, json, linq, wcf

I have a simple WCF service running which should be returning data from the Northwind database using LINQ to SQL.  I am able to call the service and return results just fine.  When i tweaked out my class a bit i am getting the correct number of rows, but the are all blank {}.

This is the class i am selecting into with my LINQ query:

```
[DataContract]
public class ProductView {
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public short? UnitsInStock { get; set; }
    public ProductView() { }
    public ProductView(Product item) {
        ProductID = item.ProductID;
        ProductName = item.ProductName;
        UnitsInStock = item.UnitsInStock;
    }
}
```

This is my LINQ query:

```
using (NorthwindDataContext context = new NorthwindDataContext("BLAH")) {
   var products = from p in context.Products select new ProductView (p);
   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(products);
}
```

Chrome Developer shows the results returned as "[{},{},{},{}]" however if i inspect the object while debugging and prior to serializing it, i can see all the ProductView objects and their relative properties.

I know i am missing something simple, i just cant for the life of me figure it out...
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that by adding `[DataContract]` to your class, you're telling the json converter that it should only pay attention to properties with a `[DataMember]` attribute on them. Since none of your properties have that attribute, none of them get serialized.

Either add DataMember attributes to your properties, or remove the DataContract attribute from your class.